# Keep Outlookinstance after Messageitem.send

Tags: vb.net, outlook

We've got a little problem (again) with Outlook,
if there is no instance of Outlook running, and you create an appointment item in Vb.net, as soon as the display method returns, the outlookapplication terminates, disappears from the Taskmanager, and if you try to do any further calls to the application or the item, you get the "RPC Server not available" exception.

**So my question is:** How to prevent the Application from terminating if it wasn't start by the user.

Additional Info:
this really only appears if you try to run the program while outlook is closed, so the createAppointment method really has to create a new task.
If the application is already running, so the user started an instance, there is no problem.

Code for creating Appointment:

```
  Public Function CreateAppointment(Appointment As InternalAppointmentClass) As Boolean
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
    Dim OlAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = CType(OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem), Outlook.AppointmentItem)

    With OlAppItem
        .Start = Appointment .StartDate
        .Subject = Appointment .Subject
        .Location = Appointment .Location
        .End = Appointment .EndDate.addDays(1)
        .ReminderSet = False
        .AllDayEvent = True
        .BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olFree
        .MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting
        .ResponseRequested = True
        If IsNothing(.UserProperties.Find("DBID")) Then
            .UserProperties.Add("DBID", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, 1)
        End If
        .UserProperties("DBID").Value = getAppointmentChecksum(Appointment)
        'only need first element, because
        .Recipients.Add(CreateRecepientsAndCC(Appointment)(0))
        .Recipients.ResolveAll()
        .Display(True)
    End With

   'at this Point the problem is first visible

    If OlAppItem.Saved Then
        UpdateStatusAndSave(OlAppItem)
        CreateAppointment = True
    End If

    OutlookApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a pretty simple solution:
before creating/editing/deleting an Appointment in Outlook we call:

```
        Dim si As New ProcessStartInfo("Outlook.exe")
        si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        Process.Start(si)
```

which starts a real, for the user visible Outlook-instance, as long as this instance is alive, the connection to Outlook will not be closed, so no RPC-Exception

Answer (score 0):

Why not always create an instance of Outlook.Application object on demand of keeping a global object?

Comment: I think I did this her, at the start of the method, when I need it, I create the instance and if I dont need it any more, I close it.

Comment: Try to call OlAppItem.GetInspector and call Inspector.Display. Keep the reference to the Inspector object until you are done.